# Is dynamic injection through Class.forName() method invocation always harmful?

Tags: java, reflection, sonarqube

Currently in our application, sonarqube is giving error for below 2 code snippets.

1.

```
public void method1(String a) {
     Class clazz = Class.forName(a);
     B b = (B) clazz.newInstance();
 }
```

As per my understanding, in this case sonar is complaining because a hacker can pass a class name at runtime 
to that method and he\she can execute malicious code using reflection. 
Now, my question is how the above code will execute if the class passed by the hacker is not in the classpath.
Shouldn't it throw ClassNotFoundException\NoClassDefFoundError ?
Also, if that class is not implemented or extended by Class B, it will throw ClassCastException ?
So, Could you please tell me  how this code is not safe ?

2.

```
public void method2(String fieldName) {
 Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.test.TestClass");
 Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
 //
 }
```

In this case, sonar is complaining about getDeclaredField(). Could you please let me know whats the harm in calling 
that method specially when I am not setting the accessibility by calling setAccessible() method.

If at all above mentioned 2 code snippets are harmful, it will be helpful if you can provide the solution.

Thanks

Comment: It's also unreliable because the compiler/IDE can't analyze it at compile time. Why are you wanting to do this? There's usually a better way.

Comment: "Shouldn't it throw ClassNotFoundException\NoClassDefFoundError" yes, it would. But there are lots more classes on your classpath than you probably intend.

Comment: Please post the exact error message of Sonar. Otherwise we could only assume Sonar intentions.

Comment: Note the difference between "not safe" and "not secure". They are different things. Which one do you mean?